# Using a pointer to pointer to print the content of an array of pointer in C

Tags: c, pointers

I  created two programs in C which print the content of an array of pointers
(I used a pointer to pointer to print the content of array)
In the second program I did not expected to print them fine because in for loop I use *p2; instead of **p2;  [fro(..;*p2;..)]
I expected that my second program will not print anything in terminal (It will never find NULL)
why does this happen??

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
char *p1[100]={"jan","feb","jul","mar","apr","may","june","july","august","sept","oct","nov","dec"};
char**p2;
p2=p1;
for(p2=p1;**p2;p2++)      
   {
    
        printf("\n the words are %s",*p2);  
   }
return 0;
}
```

My second program :

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
char *p1[100]={"jan","feb","jul","mar","apr","may","june","july","august","sept","oct","nov","dec"};
char**p2;
p2=p1;
for(p2=p1;*p2;p2++)      
   {
    printf("\n the words are %s",*p2);  
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first program is invalid.

1.

`**p` references the character and there is no pointer referencing the empty string (as you check id the **character** is not zero).  UB

It has to be:

```
char *p1[100]={"jan","feb","jul","mar","apr","may","June",
               "july","august","sept","oct","nov","dec", ""};
```

2. 

Remaining elements of the array are initialized to NULL so this program is current if you do not initialize all of the array elements to not NULL.

```
char *p1[100]={"jan","feb","jul","mar","apr","may","June",
               "july","august","sept","oct","nov","dec", };
```

Answer (score 0):

The second program works `p1` has less initializers than array elements, so the remaining array elements are set to NULL.  When `p2` iterates through the loop it checks if what `p2` points to , i.e. `*p2` is NULL.  On each of the first 12 iterations it points an element containing the address of one of the string constants in the list.  On the 13th iteration it points to an element containing NULL so the condition becomes false.

The first program triggers [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) because it is checking the first character of each string in the list, and on the 13th iteration it dereferences a NULL pointer.